# Access my router from another location

Tags: router, ip

My router runs a server that I can access when I go to 192.186.1.1

It allows me to change settings and such with that.

Knowing my own IP, is it possible to access my router from any location?  If so, how?

Comment: Barring any other settings you may have set, yes.

Comment: Depends on your router. How about you throw us a bone and tell us what kind it is, and what you've tried so far? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a linksys router (default IP for it is usually 192.168.1.1).  There is a setting under the "Administration" area that says "Remote Management", select "Enable".  Make sure you change the "Remote management port" from 8080 to something else.

You need to know your WAN IP, once you know that you open a web browser, punch in the ip and the port and you should be able to access the router.

```
example: 10.10.10.10:35602
```

[Here](http://ui.linksys.com/files/E3200/1.0.00/Management.html) is an emulator already at the management page for reference.

If your router is not a linksys the process is similar, but the location of the remote management settings will vary.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is the default (internal) IP for many routers.

Comment: I covered that aspect in my answer as well, considering 3Com, Asus, Buffalo, TP-Link and many others use that default IP.  The method for enabling remote administration is the same regardless of router brand.  Find the remote admin option and turn it on, change the port and you're good to go.